# Как с помощью vuejs-метода добавить html в DOM

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom

Есть кнопка

```
<button @click="sendMsg('тескст сообщения ')" ><button/>
```

По клику на которую вызывается функция вида:

```
sendMsg(msg){
 return '<li>${msg}</li>'
}
```

Как передать сформированный в методе тег в уже существующий элемент DOM?

Answer (score 1):

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <button type="button" @click="sendMsg('тескст сообщения')">ClickMe</button>
      <ul v-if="msg" v-html="msg"></ul>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      msg: undefined,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    sendMsg(msg) {
      this.msg = `<li>${ msg }</li>`
    },
  },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.16/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста добавьте дисклеймер, о том что использование v-html может приводить к выполнению зловредного кода на странице. Новичкам это может быть не очевидно.